# Integral over an interval of the normal distribution

Tags: probability

Assume that $f$ is the normal distribution function with mean equal to $0$ and variance equal to $\sigma^2$.

Set some interval $I=[a,b]$ in $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Denote the integral of $f$ over $I$ by $S_I(\sigma^2)$.

My question: is $S_I(\sigma^2)$ monotonous (decreasing?) as $\sigma^2$ increases continuously? Or is it dependent on $I$ or the initial value of $\sigma^2$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this plot and the interval around $2$. It's clear that the integral is not monotonous with $\sigma$. So in general case, it depends both on interval (for symmetric or wide enough intervals, the integral is monotonous) and on initial value of $\sigma^2$ (for each interval there is such $\sigma_0$, so for $\sigma>\sigma_0$ the integral is monotonous).

[image]